# Read QRcode from scanned document in R

Tags: r

I am using the `qrcode_gen()` function from the `qrcode` package in `R` to generate a QR code, then place it on the top of a document (example linked below). The document is printed, written on, scanned, and stored as an image (.png) file. I would like to be able to read the QR code in `R` to get the imbedded text back. Eventually the whole process will be semi-automated in an `Rshiny` app, so I am hoping to keep everything in `R`, and not need to use an outside web tool to read the code.

Has anyone done this? I'm open to using the `reticulate` package to interface `R` with Python if necessary, but do not have coding experience in Python.

Example:

```
# produce a QR code

library(qrcode)
example_text <- "this is a test"
qrcode_test <- qrcode_gen(dataString = example_text, plotQRcode=T, dataOutput=T)
```

[Example of QR code printed on one of our documents.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wcx5.png)

Comment: did you get to solve it?

Comment: Exacavting an old question that I came across in a search. I haven't been actively maintaining this, but hopefully it should help you. https://github.com/brianwdavis/quadrangle