# Read the QR from a pdf file

Tags: r

I'd like to read a QR code located somewhere inside a pdf file using R.

The following code should create a pdf file with a QR code for demo (the actual documents might have multiple pages, lines of text, graphs, tables and/or images, one can expect not to find 2 QR codes on the same file though)

```
library(qrcode)
pdf(file = "1.pdf")
qrcode_test <- qrcode_gen(dataString = "I want to extract this string", plotQRcode=T, dataOutput=T)
dev.off()
```

a very similar question that unfortunately didn't got replied for over a year:
[Read QRcode from scanned document in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952700/read-qrcode-from-scanned-document-in-r)

Bonus points for a way to check if the pdf has a QR code in the first place

Comment: Note: Could not use "QR Code" on the title because SO didn't let me use word "code"

Comment: note sure if there is a out of the box solution in R. If you have a internet conection available you could remote control a webbrowser and let some website do the job, than scrap: https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx

Comment: This is an older project but should still work. https://github.com/brianwdavis/quadrangle